# How does owncloud sync work? Is it normal that it sync although files exist?

Tags: sync, samba, owncloud

I am currently testing owncloud 7 + windows sync client and I am facing problems.

For example, oC sync is syncing although files already exist on the client! (Since it's a homeserver, resync of GBs of data is a waste of bandwidth/resources).

Example 1: I set up the test installation to `https://192.168.200.1/owncloud`. GBs of data got synced although I copied them in advance to %USERPROFILE%\ownCloud - exactly as they are on the server. Is this normal? Why?

Example 2: I changed my test setup to use `https://my-domain.net/owncloud`. In the sync tool I did "Modify account". Did not change any of the files on the client or on the server. Guess what, oC blindly syncs everything! "Downloading xyz (31 MB of 5GB, file 10 of 5034)"

Based on that I tried to understand how oC sync works. I read now a couple of times through "APPENDIX B: ARCHITECTURE" but I just don't get it.

It states that earlier versions used "Modification time" which is a really bad idea when it comes to sync and may result in data loss. Then they state they use en eTag field:

> ownCloud 4.5 introduced a unique number, which changes whenever the file changes

But it does not state where this is stored, how it changes and who guarantees that it does.

My data lies on a a samba share. What happens if it is modified there?

(I asked by question already on the oC forums but got no responses)